# html dropdown box working in editor but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a bit of trouble getting my code to work properly once it is loaded up onto my website.  While it is in my .html editor, it works fine, but once I put it on the server, it does not (You can see it @ http://www.jump2it.net/delivery.html).

The code is supposed to allow you to choose a city name from a drop down box, then display what our minimum rental amount is for that city in one text box and our delivery amount for that city in a second text box.  When I run the code inside my editor, it runs fine, but once I upload it or run it locally on my computer, it gives me the answer of 'undefined' in both of the text boxes.

Any help that you can throw my way would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AnEventHasOccurred() 
        {
           var sel = document.getElementById("selectone");
           document.getElementById("eventlog1").value = "" + "" + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value1 + "\n";
           document.getElementById("eventlog2").value = "" + "" + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value2 + "\n";
        }
</script></p>
```

And here is my .html code:

```
<table border="1" width="60%" height="17">
   <tr>
   <td width="40%" height="11" align="left" valign="top">
     <p style="margin:0;"><b>Please Choose Your City and Zipcode Below</b></p>
     <p style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>
     <p style="margin:0;"><b>&nbsp;</b><select id="selectone" onchange="AnEventHasOccurred()">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value1="$100" option value2="FREE">Peachtree City - 30269</option>
       <option value="Newnan - Min. Rental=$100, Delivery=Free">Newnan - 30265</option>
       <option value="Newnan - Min. Rental=$100, Delivery=Free">Newnan - 30263</option>
    </select></p>
</td>
<td width="43%" height="11">
<p style="margin:0;"><b>Min. Rental Amount</b></p>
<p style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>
   <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="eventlog1" NAME="result" VALUE="" size="20"/>
</td>
<td width="34%" height="11">
<p style="margin: 0"><b>Delivery Fee</b></p>
<p style="margin: 0">&nbsp;</p>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="eventlog2" NAME="result" VALUE="" size="20"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript code to:

```
   document.getElementById("eventlog1").value = "" + "" +
                 sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value1') + "\n";
   document.getElementById("eventlog2").value = "" + "" + 
                 sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2') + "\n";
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zCMdV/295/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Meda.  That fixed it on the 1st try!

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing via attributes.

```
sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].attributes["value1"]
```